# How can I speed up completed group polling?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm struggling to speed up Spring Integration aggregator component because it releases completed message groups once per second and I need it to be faster.

spring.xml snippet:

```
<int:channel id="fromRabbit">
    <int:queue capacity="4096"/>
</int:channel>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fromRabbit" queue-names="si.test.queue"
                                  connection-factory="connectionFactory"                                                                              
                                  concurrent-consumers="5"
                                  task-executor="myExecutor"/>

<bean id="aggregatorBean" class="ResponseAggregator" />
<bean id="correlationBean" class="CustomCorrelationStrategy"/>
<bean id="releaseBean" class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy">
    <constructor-arg value="${gcmPollSize}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="60000"/>
</bean>

<int:aggregator id="myAggregator"
                auto-startup="true"
                input-channel="fromRabbit"
                output-channel="completeChannel"
                group-timeout="10000"
                message-store="responseMessageStore"
                send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
                send-timeout="100"
                ref="aggregatorBean"                    
                correlation-strategy="correlationBean"
                release-strategy="releaseBean"                    
                method="handle">
</int:aggregator>


<int:channel id="completeChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="4096"/>
</int:channel>
<bean id="pl" class="CompleteChannelPoller"/>
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="completeChannel" ref="pl" method="handle">
</int:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:poller id="customPoller" task-executor="myExecutor" receive-timeout="0" max-messages-per-poll="1000" fixed-rate="100" default="true"/>
```

CompleteChannelPoller receives messages once per second. I cannot understand why.

Comment: You should supply you question with logs to confirm the issue. Plus I don't see reason to use those `queue` channel one by one. And with the fact that `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` is multi-threaded anyway

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean one by one? amqp->fromRabbit->completeChannel. Can it be done easier?  Here is the log http://pastebin.com/RmMTAZZX

Comment: If I remove <queue/> elements, nothing changes. It's still 1 group per second at the 'completeChannel'.